# display: table-cell with multiple rows (equal height columns, multiple rows)

Tags: css

Given a list:

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

And this CSS:

```
ul { display: table; width: 600px; }
li { display: table-cell; width: 33%; }
```

You'd expect 3 rows of 3 columns, each 200px-ish wide. But it seems the `li` width is ignored.

Is there any way to force rows with `display: table-cell` without adding in extra markup?

**Edit:** 
Also, I'm using `table-cell` because I want then entire row to have the same height (despite varying content), as I want to position something in all three cells in each row, but at the bottom of the lowest cell. That is a confusing sentence I know.

**Basically I want to turn a bunch of `li`s into equal height columns, but with multiple rows *only using CSS*. All the equal height column solutions I've seen can't do this.**

Comment: I don't see multiply rows, I see one row with 9 cells. So, if you want a table, why aren't you using a table? Or if you really want to minimise markup, use `<div>` instead of `<li>` (so you can dispense with the `<ul>`) and give them `display: inline-block;`. Done.

Comment: Exactly. That's what I get as well. I want multiple rows, can't edit markup, so can't use tables.

Comment: If you have restrictions like being unable to change the markup, you should always say so in your question. That will greatly reduce the number of wrong answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is the](http://jsfiddle.net/aUHpA/) solution I came up with.

The markup is slightly modified, to remove the whitespace. This is because with the `li`s set to `display: inline`, the newlines between them will take up some of the width.

Comment: how to get full height background?

Answer (score 14):

You can give `display:inline-table` instead of `display:table-cell` to LI. Write like this:

```
ul { display: table; width: 600px; font-size:0;}
li { display: inline-table; width: 33%;background:red; font-size:15px;}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/56FGT/1/

Comment: As per my edit, I need to use `table-cell` as I want all the cells in the row to have the same height.

Answer (score 3):

If you want css to show 3 `<li>`s in one row each of width `200px` in same `<ul>`, You can try something like this with your above html:

```
ul { list-style: none outside none; width: 600px; }
li { float: left;display: block;width: 200px; height: 33px; }​
```

### Demo

Comment: Using floats is the most cross-browser way (works on all CSS-enabled browsers), and a simple one at that. Just remember to use `clear` on the first element after the `ul` element, to prevent other content from appearing to the right of the last item.

Comment: As per my edit, I need to use `table-cell` as I want all the cells in the row to have the same height.

Comment: @cainmi And you don't know beforehand how high the content of each is going to be?

Comment: @MrLister No, variable content.

Comment: @cainmi Then I'm afraid you'll have do use Javascript to change the content into a real table. Otherwise I haven't found a way to have the vertical alignment features of table cells AND break this into three rows at the same time.

Comment: @MrLister I was afraid of that. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no semantic solution. It should be wrapper container for every set of items to apply same height to them. But it's possible to solve design problem (kinda make a grid)
here is an example how to make it: [multiple rows with same height on a line](http://jsfiddle.net/dmitrismirnov/Fzjct/)

Answer (score 1):

I am using `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: top`

But if you want background that stretches with height as well, javascript is the only way (that I can think of)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the markup, it can be done without faking a table. You can make the list items `display:block` instead of `display:table-cell`.

By the way, 33% of `600px` is not 200 pixels. Use `200px`!

Edit:
If you know what the maximum height of the content is going to be, you can use that as the height for all list items of course, and use vertical-align or line-height to align the contents. (But as that's not an option either, the solutions that don't change the markup are out.)

Comment: As per my edit, I need to use `table-cell` as I want all the cells in the row to have the same height.